# Content element inside Toolbar component doesn't work

Tags: css, sapui5

I'm trying to build a table with button on table's header. I'm guiding from [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Selection/preview).

This is my code:

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
        xmlns="sap.m"
        xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
        xmlns:t="sap.ui.table"
        height="100%"
        controllerName="xxxxx" 
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="CONFIGURACIÓN DE LA CUENTA" navButtonPress="onCancel" showNavButton="true">

        <content>
            <f:SimpleForm id="form_requerimiento_datos_generales" minWidth="1024" 
                          maxContainerCols="2" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                          labelSpanL="4" labelSpanM="4"
                          emptySpanL="0" emptySpanM="0" columnsL="2" columnsM="2"
                          validateFieldGroup="onValidateFieldGroup">
                <f:content>


                    <core:Title text="Suscripciones"/>
                    <t:Table
                        rows="{/Subscriptions?$filter=UserSystem eq '1'}"
                        selectionMode="None"
                        visibleRowCount="7">
                        <t:toolbar>
                            <content>
                                <Title id="title" text="Listado de Suscripciones" />
                                <ToolbarSpacer/>                        
                                <Button
                                    icon="sap-icon://add"
                                    tooltip="Agregar Suscripciones"
                                    press="addSuscription"/>
                            </content>
                        </t:toolbar>
                        <t:columns>
                            <!--columns-->
                        </t:columns>
                    </t:Table>       
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </content>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

I have following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/content.js' from https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/content.js: 0 - NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/content.js'.
```

I don't know why I get this error. I think that It's in this part of code:

```
<t:toolbar>
    <content>
        <Title id="title" text="Listado de Suscripciones" />
        <ToolbarSpacer/>                        
        <Button
            icon="sap-icon://add"
            tooltip="Agregar Suscripciones"
            press="addSuscription"/>
    </content>
</t:toolbar>
```

I don't know why **content label is not accepted inside toolbar label** (In example this works). When I take off content label of my page. I don't get error messages.

I would like to know what doing for to solve my problem.

Thanks for help me!

**UPDATE 1**

I solved already my problem but Now I have another problem. I have a problem with CSS of table header (This is overlapped with table body):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label `<t:toolbar>` is the aggregation name and it expects a toolbar inside it. 
So, ideally `<t:toolbar>` is followed by a `sap.m.Toolbar` control.

As to why it is throwing: `sap/m/content` error is because,  it is expecting a control after the `<t:toolbar>`. Also, since your default namespace is `sap.m` so it looks for control ( in this case you have specified content) in the default namespace.There is no such control as `sap.m.content`. Thus, an error.

If you will check your guiding source, you will see they have an `<m:Toolbar>` after `<toolbar>` aggregation

Here is the updated code:

```
                      <t:toolbar>
                            <Toolbar>
                                <content>
                                    <Title id="title" text="Listado de Suscripciones" />
                                    <ToolbarSpacer/>                        
                                    <Button
                                        icon="sap-icon://add"
                                        tooltip="Agregar Suscripciones"
                                        press="addSuscription"/>
                                </content>
                            </Toolbar>
                        </t:toolbar>
```